# FFMPEG - Chaining commands for time lapse, size, and h.264 recursively through a directory

Tags: ffmpeg, chaining

Working on converting videos over a directory structure. Currently I tried this:

```
for i in *.mov; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v "setpts=0.1*PTS" -an -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "${i/-lapse.mov}"
done
```

Didn't get to the resizing but already realize this won't work this way. 
Trying to make it work in this order: Timelapse video, convert size to X x Y, and make sure quality is decent.

Haven't worked too much with FFMPEG so any help is appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying in windows? Is it MS-DOS command? If that is the case, you need to correct your command as below:

```
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -filter:v "setpts=0.1*PTS" -an -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "%%i-lapse.mov")
```

If it is anything to do with ffmpeg errors, rather than dos command format errors, please do post the error that you observe

Comment: I'm on a mac. The question is really related to how best to chain the various commands. Thanks!